# TypeError: PanelReview() got an unexpected keyword argument 'panelmember'

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm unable to post a review from react side, However at backend it's working fine.
When I hit button to submit review this error comes on frontend

[image]

And at Backend
Django expecting something else and error is

```
Internal Server Error: /api/panel/1/reviews/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\eCommerce_Projects\remote-hospital\panel\views\panelmembers_views.py", line 66, in createPanelMemberReview
    review = PanelReview.objects.create(
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 451, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 503, in __init__
    raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: PanelReview() got an unexpected keyword argument 'panelmember'
[27/Jun/2021 11:48:07] "POST /api/panel/1/reviews/ HTTP/1.1" 500 121143
```

**Problematic Code:**
`PanelMemberDetailScreen.js` Removed Irrelevant Lines

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Alert,
  Row,
  Col,
  Image,
  ListGroup,
  Button,
  Card,
  Form,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import Rating from "../components/Rating";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";
import Message from "../components/Message";
import { listPanelDetails, createPanelReview } from "../actions/panelActions";
import { PANEL_CREATE_REVIEW_RESET } from "../constants/panelConstants";

function PanelMemberDetailScreen({ match, history }) {
    
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
    const [comment, setComment] = useState("");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const panelDetails = useSelector((state) => state.panelDetails);
    const { loading, error, panelmember } = panelDetails;

    const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
    const { userInfo } = userLogin;

    const panelReviewCreate = useSelector((state) => state.panelReviewCreate);
    const {
        loading: loadingPanelReview,
        error: errorPanelReview,
        success: successPanelReview,
    } = panelReviewCreate;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (successPanelReview) {
        setRating(0);
        setComment("");
        dispatch({ type: PANEL_CREATE_REVIEW_RESET });
        }

        dispatch(listPanelDetails(match.params.id));
    }, [dispatch, match, successPanelReview]);

    

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(
        createPanelReview(match.params.id, {
            rating,
            comment,
        })
        );
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <Link to='/panel' className='btn btn-success my-3'>Go Back</Link>
            {
               loading ?
                    <Loader />
                    : error ?  <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
                    : (
                        <div>
                            <Row>
                           <Col md={6}>
                           <Image src={panelmember.image} alt={panelmember.name} fluid />
                           <Card className="my-3 p-2 rounded card border-success"  >
                           <Card.Title><h2>Reviews</h2></Card.Title>
                           {panelmember.reviews.length === 0 && <Message variant='success'>No Reviews | Be First To Review Our Panel Member</Message>}
                           <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                                        {panelmember.reviews.map((review) => (
                                            <ListGroup.Item key={review._id}>
                                                <strong>{review.name}</strong>
                                                <Rating value={review.rating} color='#f8e825' />
                                                <p>{review.createdAt.substring(0, 10)}</p>
                                                <p>{review.comment}</p>
                                            </ListGroup.Item>
                                        ))}
                                        <ListGroup.Item>
                                            <h4>Write a review</h4>

                                            {loadingPanelReview && <Loader />}
                                            {successPanelReview && <Message variant='success'>Review Submitted</Message>}
                                            {errorPanelReview && <Message variant='danger'>{errorPanelReview}</Message>}

                                            {userInfo ? (
                                                <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                                                    <Form.Group controlId='rating'>
                                                        <Form.Label>Rating</Form.Label>
                                                        <Form.Control
                                                            as='select'
                                                            value={rating}
                                                            onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)}
                                                        >
                                                            <option value=''>Select...</option>
                                                            <option value='1'>1 - Poor</option>
                                                            <option value='2'>2 - Fair</option>
                                                            <option value='3'>3 - Good</option>
                                                            <option value='4'>4 - Very Good</option>
                                                            <option value='5'>5 - Excellent</option>
                                                        </Form.Control>
                                                    </Form.Group>

                                                    <Form.Group controlId='comment'>
                                                        <Form.Label>Type Your Comment Here</Form.Label>
                                                        <Form.Control
                                                            as='textarea'
                                                            row='5'
                                                            value={comment}
                                                            onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
                                                        ></Form.Control>
                                                    </Form.Group>

                                                    <Button
                                                        disabled={loadingPanelReview}
                                                        type='submit'
                                                        variant='success'
                                                    >
                                                        Submit
                                                    </Button>

                                                </Form>
                                            ) : (
                                                    <Message variant='success'>Please <Link to='/login'>login</Link> to write a review</Message>
                                                )}
                                        </ListGroup.Item>
                                    </ListGroup>
                           </Card>
                           </Col>
                           
                          
                           
                            </Row>
                        </div>
                    )
            }
        </div>)
}

export default PanelMemberDetailScreen;
```

`panelReducers.js`

```
export const panelReviewCreateReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case PANEL_CREATE_REVIEW_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true }

        case PANEL_CREATE_REVIEW_SUCCESS:
            return { loading: false, success: true, }

        case PANEL_CREATE_REVIEW_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }

        case PANEL_CREATE_REVIEW_RESET:
            return {}

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

`panelActions.js`

```
export const createPanelReview = (panelId, review) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: PANEL_CREATE_REVIEW_REQUEST
        })

        const {
            userLogin: { userInfo },
        } = getState()

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`
            }
        }

        const { data } = await axios.post(
            `/api/panel/${panelId}/reviews/`,
            review,
            config
        )
        dispatch({
            type: PANEL_CREATE_REVIEW_SUCCESS,
            payload: data,
        })



    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: PANEL_CREATE_REVIEW_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.detail
                ? error.response.data.detail
                : error.message,
        })
    }
}
```

`views.py`

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def createPanelMemberReview(request, pk):
    user = request.user
    panelmember = PanelMember.objects.get(_id=pk)
    data = request.data

    # 1 - Review already exists
    alreadyExists = panelmember.panelreview_set.filter(user=user).exists()
    if alreadyExists:
        content = {'detail': 'Panel Member is already reviewed'}
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # 2 - No Rating or 0
    elif data['rating'] == 0:
        content = {'detail': 'Please select a rating'}
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # 3 - Create review
    else:
        review = PanelReview.objects.create(
            user=user,
            panelmember=panelmember,
            name=user.first_name,
            rating=data['rating'],
            comment=data['comment'],
        )

        reviews = panelmember.panelreview_set.all()
        panelmember.numReviews = len(reviews)

        total = 0
        for i in reviews:
            total += i.rating

        panelmember.rating = total / len(reviews)
        panelmember.save()

        return Response('Review Added')
```

`models.py`

```
class PanelReview(models.Model):
    panel = models.ForeignKey(PanelMember, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rating)
```

API ENDPOINT for `POST` request `/api/panel/str:pk/reviews/'

**I Believe there is problem at frontend posting the review as I feel im not passing correct argument as Primary Key to know django for which panelmember this post request is, while testing through Postman API working fine and accepting the post requests along with data. Please highlight where the problem is and how this could be solved . Thank you**

Comment: Can you add the `PanelReview` model class?

Comment: @JPG I added `PanelReview` model class in question detail. Please take a look.

Comment: found the error I named `panel` inside the view as `panelmember`, there was a problem in the `views.py ` @JPG

Comment: Thanx for bringing the idea to look into `PanelReview` model class @JPG

Answer (score 0):

There was problem in `views.py`

**Correct Code:**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def createPanelMemberReview(request, pk):
    user = request.user
    panel = PanelMember.objects.get(_id=pk)
    data = request.data

    # 1 - Review already exists
    alreadyExists = panel.panelreview_set.filter(user=user).exists()
    if alreadyExists:
        content = {'detail': 'Panel Member is already reviewed'}
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # 2 - No Rating or 0
    elif data['rating'] == 0:
        content = {'detail': 'Please select a rating'}
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # 3 - Create review
    else:
        review = PanelReview.objects.create(
            user=user,
            panel=panel,
            name=user.first_name,
            rating=data['rating'],
            comment=data['comment'],
        )

        reviews = panel.panelreview_set.all()
        panel.numReviews = len(reviews)

        total = 0
        for i in reviews:
            total += i.rating

        panel.rating = total / len(reviews)
        panel.save()

        return Response('Review Added')
```

Basically I changed variable from `panelmeber` to `panel` matching with `PanelReview` model class. Now this is working fine. And I was totally wrong. There was a problem at `backend`.